# Why doesn't the count match the value for the SQL query?

Tags: php, mysqli

I cannot really explain my problem that well, but here is the code that should:

```
<?php
   ...
   class Keys {
            public $ids = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
            public $fnames = array("Joan", "Max", "Lori", "William", "Emily", "James");
            public $lnames = array("Williams", "Helder", "Doe", "Must", "Deen", "Harthwell");
            public $ages = array(32, 15, 19, 25, 17, 8);
   }
   $keys = new Keys; // instiantate an object as an instance of Keys

   $sqlQueries = array(); // empty array to make SQL queries

   for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
        foreach($keys as $field => $value) {
            for($j = 0; $j < count($value); $j++) {
                array_push($sqlQueries, "INSERT INTO students VALUES($value[$j])");
            }
        }
   } // adds queries to array

   for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
        if(mysqli_query($connection, $sqlQueries[$i])) {
            echo "Data added successfully!";
        } else {
            die("Couldn't add data to table: " . mysqli_error($connection));
        }
    } // validates queries
    ...
?>
```

I have created a class called `Keys` with the values I wanted for the SQL queries. I define an object to be an instance of this new class. Then, I define an empty array of the queries I am going to implement. Inside the first loop, I attempt to create the queries with the values from my object. Every completed query is "pushed" to the `$sqlQueries` array. In the second loop, I validate the queries. But, I get the following error at my output:

```
Couldn't add data to table: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

I know this means that the amount of data is not even with the table. But I cannot figure out why I have this problem. I have looked at a lot of sources, but none of them helped.

Does anyone have an idea?

### EDIT:

I attempted the methods of all 3 answers, and out of all of them, @lps' answer is currently the closest to my solution. Now, my error is:

```
Couldn't add data to table: Unknown column 'age' in 'field list'
```

### EDIT 2:

A new answer came in, realizing my error in my code, and that's done. But, now I have an error saying this:

```
Couldn't add data to table: Unknown column 'Joan' in 'field list'
```

### EDIT 3:

A comment under @lps' answer came in, which removed the error about the unknown 'Joan' column. Now, I'm getting an error saying:

```
Couldn't add data to table: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

### FINAL UPDATE:

My problem is solved! Here is my final code:

```
<?php
   ...
   class Keys {
            public $fnames = array("Joan", "Max", "Lori", "William", "Emily", "James");
            public $lnames = array("Williams", "Helder", "Doe", "Must", "Deen", "Harthwell");
            public $ages = array(32, 15, 19, 25, 17, 8);
   }
   $keys = new Keys; // instiantate an object as an instance of Keys

   $sqlQueries = array(); // empty array to make SQL queries

   for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO students (fname, lname, avg_grade) VALUES "; // base query
        $values = array(); // empty array of values
        foreach($keys as $field => $value) {
            array_push($values, $value[$i]); // pushes each value to $values array
        }
        $query .= "(" . implode(',', $values) . ")"; // adds each value of array to the query
        array_push($sqlQueries, $query); // pushes complete query to $sqlQueries array
   } // adds queries to the $sqlQueries array

   var_dump($sqlQueries); // Just wanted to see my queries

   $query = "SELECT * FROM students";
   $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
   if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE FROM students");
   } // cleans out the table if there are any duplicate queries

   for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
        if(mysqli_query($connection, $sqlQueries[$i])) {
            $recordID = mysqli_insert_id($connection);
            echo "Data added successfully! The last inserted ID was " . $recordID; // outputs success message and gets last inserted ID
        } else {
            die("Couldn't add data to table: " . mysqli_error($connection)); // Outputs an error if there was a failure attempting to implement data
        }
    } // validates queries
    ...
?>
```

Comment: Why are you using `array_push`? Just combine the 2 loops to run `mysqli_query` on `$value[$j]`

Comment: If you dump `$sqlQueries`, you might see the issue.

Comment: Sorry, @Bijan, your idea doesn't work. I still get the error.

Comment: I think the problem is your concatenation of `VALUES($value[$j])` with rest of query.

Comment: Please show the table definition of `students`. imo, it is always useful to list the columns that the values will match to in the `insert` statement..

Comment: @ObinnaNwakwue In regards to the duplicate key error, that is because the id field is a primary key so needs to be unique.  Since you are supplying the ids in the ocde, you wuold need to empty out the table on each subsequent run. If you are using mysql you can do `delete from students` and it will empty the ENTIRE table.  If the field is set to auto-increment you can remove the ids entirely from the code and the database will  automatically assign an id when an insert is done.

Comment: @lps, your suggestion is absolutely correct. If I do that, I don't have to go into my MySQL database and clean everything out manually. I tried that, and it works!

Comment: @ObinnaNwakwue great!  keep in mind that now that you're letting the database create the id for you, it will just keep adding entries regardless of whether or not they are duplicates in real life.  Since the id is unique, you can use that field to identify particular entries in the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the method explained by LPS. The message you are getting now means that need to create a field named `age` in your database structure. Check your data base, I am pretty sure the field `age` do not exist.

**EDIT:**

I am glad to see my previous answer solved your error, the new error you are getting now (`Couldn't add data to table: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'`) means that the field `id` in your database is a `primary` field and this type of fields do not allow repeated (duplicated) values. So, I guess the code ran well once and inserted the values in your DB and now it can't do it again because it find the value `1` already exist in the field `id` and the error handler in your code stop the script.

*To test if I am right, try this:*

Go to your database, the records should be already inserted, delete them and run the script, it should run with no problems and if you check your DB the records should be there again. Let the records there and try to run the script, if you receive the same error again this means I am right.

I can think in two simple options to solve the issue (depending on the final behavior you want):

*1) To insert a new record every time (probably the best option):*

Make sure the field `id` has the attribute `autoincrement` and don't try to insert and ID, let MySQL to create the ID for you. Thats all.

This way the first time you run the script `Joan` is going to have the `id` number 1 and the 2nd time there is going to be 2 records with the name `Joan`: the ID number `1` (created the first time you ran the script) and ID number `7` (created with this number because it was created after `James` who was number `6`).

The change would look like this in your code:

```
 class Keys {
        //  public $ids = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
            public $fnames = array("Joan", "Max", "Lori", "William", "Emily", "James");
            public $lnames = array("Williams", "Helder", "Doe", "Must", "Deen", "Harthwell");
            public $ages = array(32, 15, 19, 25, 17, 8);
   }
   $keys = new Keys;
```

- Note that I just commented the ID part but you could also delete it.

*2) If you want to manage the ID manually (Not recomended)*

Let your database structure the way it is and just ignore the error message if it is related to a duplicated entry.

In order to do so look for this block:

```
   for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
        if(mysqli_query($connection, $sqlQueries[$i])) {
            echo "Data added successfully!";
        } else {
            die("Couldn't add data to table: " . mysqli_error($connection));
        }
    } // validates queries
```

And replace it for:

```
   for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
        if(mysqli_query($connection, $sqlQueries[$i])) {
            echo "Data added successfully!";
        } else {
            $mysqliError = mysqli_error($connection);
            if(strpos($mysqliError, 'Couldn\'t add data to table: Duplicate entry \'') !== false && strpos($mysqliError, '\' for key \'PRIMARY\'') !== false){
                die("Couldn't add data to table: " . $mysqliError);
            }
        }
    } // validates queries
```

Comment: @ObinnaNwakwue Glad to help, edited my answer to try to help with your new issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to end up with each field as a query

`INSERT INTO students VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO students VALUES(2)`

etc in sqlQueries because you're adding each field one at a time.

Assuming you want `INSERT INTO students VALUES(1, "Joan", "Williams", 32)` you'll need to build the query differently.

Prepared statements are by far the easiest way to do this.

```
$statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO students VALUES(?,?,?,?)"); 
foreach($keys->ids as $k => $v)
{
  $statement->bind_param("issi", $keys->ids[$k], $keys->fnames[$k], $keys->lnames[$k], $keys->ages[$k]);
  $statement->execute();
}
```

Comment: I am doing the procedural method, not the object-oriented method.

Comment: $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connection); 
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, "INSERT INTO students VALUES(?,?,?,?)"); 
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "issi", $keys->ids[$k], $keys->fnames[$k], $keys->lnames[$k], $keys->ages[$k]);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

then

Comment: Sorry, but your answer doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

The resulting SQL queries are not formatted correctly.  The fields and values counts in the insert query must match.  If you don't specify any fields, then the values must match the structure of the table.

Right now your code is generating queries that look like this:

```
array(144) {
  [0]=>
  string(30) "INSERT INTO students VALUES(1)"
  [1]=>
  string(30) "INSERT INTO students VALUES(2)"
  [2]=>
  string(30) "INSERT INTO students VALUES(3)"
  [3]=>
  string(30) "INSERT INTO students VALUES(4)"
  [4]=>
  string(30) "INSERT INTO students VALUES(5)"
  [5]=>
  string(30) "INSERT INTO students VALUES(6)"
  [6]=>
  string(33) "INSERT INTO students VALUES(Joan)"
  [7]=>
  string(32) "INSERT INTO students VALUES(Max)"
  [8]=>
  string(33) "INSERT INTO students VALUES(Lori)"
  [9]=>
  string(36) "INSERT INTO students VALUES(William)"
  [10]=>
  string(34) "INSERT INTO students VALUES(Emily)"
  [11]=>
  string(34) "INSERT INTO students VALUES(James)"
  [12]=>
  string(37) "INSERT INTO students VALUES(Williams)"
  [13]=>
  string(35) "INSERT INTO students VALUES(Helder)"
  [14]=>
  string(32) "INSERT INTO students VALUES(Doe)"
  [15]=>
  string(33) "INSERT INTO students VALUES(Must)"
  [16]=>
  string(33) "INSERT INTO students VALUES(Deen)"
  [17]=>
  string(38) "INSERT INTO students VALUES(Harthwell)"
  ...
```

So, change

```
   for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
        foreach($keys as $field => $value) {
            for($j = 0; $j < count($value); $j++) {
                array_push($sqlQueries, "INSERT INTO students VALUES($value[$j])");
            }
        }
   } // adds queries to array
```

To:

```
   $string_fields = ['fnames', 'lnames'];
   for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
       $query = "INSERT INTO students (id, fname, lname, age) VALUES ";
       $values = array();
        foreach($keys as $field => $value) {
            $value = $value[$i];

            if(in_array($field, $string_fields)) {
                $value = "'" . $value . "'";
            }

            array_push($values, $value);
        }
       $query .= "(" . implode(',', $values) . ")";
       array_push($sqlQueries, $query);
   } // adds queries to array
```

This will produce the following queries:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(76) "INSERT INTO students (id, fname, lname, age) VALUES (1,'Joan','Williams',32)"
  [1]=>
  string(73) "INSERT INTO students (id, fname, lname, age) VALUES (2,'Max','Helder',15)"
  [2]=>
  string(71) "INSERT INTO students (id, fname, lname, age) VALUES (3,'Lori','Doe',19)"
  [3]=>
  string(75) "INSERT INTO students (id, fname, lname, age) VALUES (4,'William','Must',25)"
  [4]=>
  string(73) "INSERT INTO students (id, fname, lname, age) VALUES (5,'Emily','Deen',17)"
  [5]=>
  string(77) "INSERT INTO students (id, fname, lname, age) VALUES (6,'James','Harthwell',8)"
}
```

Change the code so it matches whatever the actual `students` table schema.

Comment: if you add quotes to the fname and lname values, this should be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your queries as you have it would be as follows:

```
string(30) "INSERT INTO students VALUES(1)"
[1] => string(30) "INSERT INTO students VALUES(2)"
[2] => string(30) "INSERT INTO students VALUES(3)"
[3] => string(30) "INSERT INTO students VALUES(4)"
[4] => string(30) "INSERT INTO students VALUES(5)"
[5] => string(30) "INSERT INTO students VALUES(6)"
[6] => string(33) "INSERT INTO students VALUES(Joan)"
```

There are several issues here: You're not specifying which field it needs to go into, you're only passing 1 field at a time, and you're not quoting the strings. A better way to go about it would be this:

```
$queries = [];
foreach($keys->ids as $k => $v) {
    $queries[] = "INSERT INTO students (id,first_name,last_name,age) VALUES ({$keys->ids[$k]},'{$keys->fnames[$k]}','{$keys->lnames[$k]}',{$keys->ages[$k]})";
}
```

Even better would be to use prepared statements, and insert them on this loop instead of looping through the statements again.

Comment: I think aynber's code is correct ... but you might not have adapted it ...

Answer (score 0):

You should use an ORM or ActiveRecord style data access layer.  You're walking down a well trodden path without realizing it.

Comment: What is an ORM style data access layer? What is an ActiveRecord style data access layer?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
class Keys {
            public $ids = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
            public $fnames = array("Joan", "Max", "Lori", "William", "Emily", "James");
            public $lnames = array("Williams", "Helder", "Doe", "Must", "Deen", "Harthwell");
            public $ages = array(32, 15, 19, 25, 17, 8);
   }
   $keys = new Keys;
   $str='(';
    for ($i=0; $i <6 ; $i++) { 
        foreach ($keys as $key => $value) {
                $str.=$value[$i].',';
        }
        $str=rtrim($str,',');
        $str.='),(';
    }
    $str=rtrim($str,',(');
    $query="INSERT INTO students (id, fname, lname, age) VALUES ".$str;
    var_dump($query);
?>
```

you can run this query in it will insert into database.

Comment: also doesn't add quotes around the strings.

Comment: This doesn't help. I get a syntax error regarding the query.

Comment: its working fine.the output is INSERT INTO students (id, fname, lname, age) VALUES (1,Joan,Williams,32),(2,Max,Helder,15),(3,Lori,Doe,19),(4,William,Must,25),(5,Emily,Deen,17),(6,James,Harthwell,8)                         .you may have left some syntax.so please copy this code and run .it working fine .